# Can Rails connect to MySQL using MySQL option files?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm looking at changing our database connections to use the [MySQL configuration utility](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html). Is there a way to tell Rails/ActiveRecord to use `.mylogin.cnf` instead of specifying connection info in `database.yml`?

Comment: @abeger, you have to use database.yml and specify a connection configurations via .cnf file.

Comment: @AlexanderShlenchack OK, makes sense. But how do I connect the two?

Comment: You should parse you `.cnf` file and create `database.yml`  for Rails project.

Comment: @AlexanderShlenchack OK, I see the problem. I was thinking about `.mylogin.cnf` files, you're talking about `my.cnf` files. I've clarified my question.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql2` gem uses `libmysqlclient`, which in turn can use `.mylogin.cnf` starting with 5.6, but there's no way to control its version from rails. Also there seem to be some [issues](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/710) - mysql2 0.4.2 segfaults.

Actually this is possible by setting `default_group` (= mysql login path) (and `default_file` if needed) options upon creating mysql2 connection.
But prior to rails 5 these are not passed in connection adapter, but setting blank username and using `client` login path seems to work.

For example set:

```
development:
  username: ""
  default_group: client
  database: some_db
```